# Asp.net core Add Soft delete by modelBuilder.Entity<DependenciaDisciplina>().Property<bool>("isDeleted"); but isDeleted as composite key

Tags: asp.net-core, composite-key, soft-delete

I insert the soft delete flag with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DependenciaDisciplina>().Property<bool>("isDeleted");
```

But i need to add it as a composite key

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

> I insert the soft delete flag with
>
> ```
> modelBuilder.Entity<DependenciaDisciplina>().Property<bool>("isDeleted");
> ```
>
> But i need to add it as a composite key

To [set the Composite Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-primary-key) using the Fluent API, we have to use the HasKey() method.

After check the `HasKey()` method definition, we can see that the parameter should be a string array or an expression.

[image]

So, you could use the set the composite key like this (change the Car model to your model):

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().Property<bool>("isDeleted"); 
 modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasKey(new string[] { "CarId", "isDeleted" });
```

The Car model:

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public string LicensePlate { get; set; } 
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Then, after migration, the result like this:

[image]